# Excel does not recognize special letter characters

Tags: excel, encoding

I have an Excel template which is used to extract data from a database.

- The text may have special French (è, ë, û, ù) or German letters (ü, ö, ä)
- Excel would extract it as a � sign instead.

I guess the problem is with some encoding option set by default in the Excel file. What should I do to get Excel read and display correctly the mentioned special letter signs?

As I could not solve the problem using an option that would change encoding, I tried using some formulas ([CHAR](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/char-function-bbd249c8-b36e-4a91-8017-1c133f9b837a), [CODE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/code-function-c32b692b-2ed0-4a04-bdd9-75640144b928), etc.) to make Excel read the characters and then replace it. However, the character always has the same CHAR code (63) so it seems that Excel has put the same character regardless of the differences in the special letters it could not read.

Example of expected output:

```
l'énergie
```

Actual output:

```
l'�nergie
```

I have one important constraint: I cannot use macros or user-defined functions so VBA is not an option.

Comment: Those letters are really not that special: 'è' has ASCII code 232 and 'ü' 252 (try to type ALT+0232 and ALT+0252 and you'll see). How are those letters stored in your database?

Comment: @Dominique - I do not really know. I was hoping to avoid having to contact the developers of the tool I am using to extract the data from the database to Excel. The general instruction is to have the cell formatted as Text to prevent unexpected results. So the cell in Excel has the Text style but this does not help.

Comment: Can you try writing 'è' and 'ü' in your Excel sheet? (Either using your keyboard or using the mentioned shortcut keys) I have the impression that the problem is caused by your database.

Comment: Yes - I can indeed.

Comment: What happens if you open the data in some other software? (ex. a good text editor)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad - It keeps the ugly sign in Word for example.

Comment: That's a good sign the problem is with the export and not the software. Did the developer even consider non-English characters when setting the database export up?

Comment: What happens if you open it in `Notepad++`? (a free add-in for Windows).  That should handle most anything.  If it does not display properly, then the issue is likely in the encoding of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [unicode function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unicode-function-adb74aaa-a2a5-4dde-aff6-966e4e81f16f) rather than `CODE()` and `CHAR()`.  For example, with data in **A1**, in **C1** enter:

```
=UNICODE(MID($A$1,ROW(),1))
```

and in **D1** enter:

```
=UNICHAR(C1)
```

[image]

NOTE:

I also used a unicode-compatible font.

Comment: I gave that a try - same result. The � sign is not changed. It now simply has the char code 65533 instead of 63 (which it has when I use simply CHAR). And as I explained all special characters have the same code even though I can see they represent different letters otherwise.

Comment: @papen  It appears that your special characters are being ruined during the import process.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you imply that there is no way to fix it afterwards, right?

Comment: @papen  It **might** be possible to improve the import process to preserve the unicodes.